# JUnit: Test for class method breaks compilation when class tested does not contain method

Tags: java, junit

Building a JUnit test class. It is being used as an autograder. Some of the submissions do not have all of the required class methods (even though it was part of specs). Autograder is of course only a part of the total grade (say 50%). It improves the issue of playing 500 games, to test whether they function as expected.

In addition to checking whether all methods exist, it would be nice to check if they are also callable.

JUnit test code snippet:

```
@Test
public void test_1p1t4_15() {
    // Test if callable
    try {
        Direction d1 = new Direction();
        checkMethod(d1.getClass(), "print");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        fail("Test fails:"+e.toString());
    }
}
```

A `checkMethod` function helps show when issues are related to implementation of the method, such as visibility, e.g.

```
public void checkMethod( Class cls, String fnName) {
    // Checks method validity for methods not including an argument
    try {
        Method m = cls.getMethod(fnName);
        assertNotNull(m);        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        fail("Failed: "+e.toString());
    }
}
public void checkMethod( Class cls, String fnName, Class type) {
    // Checks method validity for methods including an argument
    try {
        Method m = cls.getMethod(fnName, type);
        assertNotNull(m);        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        fail("Failed: "+e.toString());
    }
}
public void testMethod( Class cls, String fnName) {
    // Code here
}
public void testMethod( Class cls, String fnName, argType, argValue) {
    // Code here
    // Including an argument
}
```

Comment: First, the compilation error is unrelated to the code you posted. Second, just because you called `checkMethod`, does not prevent `d1.print()` from causing a compilation error if the student didn't write a `print` method. You'll need to use reflection to get and invoke the `print` method if it exists, and deduct points if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Java is not Python. Performing a runtime check for the existence of `print` doesn't save you from the compile-time error that arises if the student doesn't have a `print` method.

Comment: I agree to the last comment: maybe you start by learning about the differences between dynamic and statically compiled languages. Afterwards, you do some research on exceptions vs errors in Java.

Comment: "You'll need to use reflection to get and invoke the print method if it exists, and deduct points if it doesn't exist." @pkpnd Very interesting, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple example that demonstrates how to find and invoke a method with arguments, if the method exists. You will want to call `invokeIfExists` in your JUnit tests. You will then be able to assert that the returned value matches whatever you expect.

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class Main {

    static Object invokeIfExists(Class<?> cls, String methodName,
                                 Class<?>[] argTypes,
                                 Object callingObject, Object[] args) {
        try {
            Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, argTypes);
            return method.invoke(callingObject, args);
        } catch (SecurityException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
            System.err.println("Method " + methodName + " not found.");
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.err.println("Method " + methodName + " could not be invoked.");
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            System.err.println("Method " + methodName + " threw an exception.");
        }
        return null; // Or assert false, etc.
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Direction direction = new Direction("a", "b");

        // Tries to invoke "direction.print(123)"
        String printResult = (String) invokeIfExists(
            Direction.class, "print", new Class<?>[]{int.class},
            direction, new Object[]{123});
        System.out.println(printResult); // "Direction: a -> b and foo=123"

        // Tries to invoke "direction.doesntExist()"
        Object doesntExistResult = invokeIfExists(
            Direction.class, "doesntExist", new Class<?>[]{},
            direction, new Object[]{});
        System.out.println(doesntExistResult); // null
    }
}

class Direction {
    private String from, to;

    Direction(String from, String to) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }

    String print(int foo) {
        return "Direction: " + from + " -> " + to + " and foo=" + foo;
    }
}
```